# Deploy to iPhone, no network access

Tags: iphone, ios

I've managed to get both an iPad and iPhone hooked up to xcode, and can successfully deploy to the device.  For some reason I'm getting network errors every time I try an access a feature that requires the internet, so I think there must be some setting in XCode I'm missing.

Do I need to specifically tell xcode that I permit the device to access the network?

Comment: So to clarify some things:  these devices can access the Internet freely, yes?  And it is the device that is having the trouble accessing the Internet, not Xcode, right?

Comment: I'm not sure how to determine the network errors... but yes, the device when not hooked up to the computer can access the internet fine, and the laptop can access the internet fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with PhoneGap (used to create cross-platform apps by using HTML5).

The error I was getting was similar to this:

```
SampleApp[549:17803] ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'
```

And the solution can be found here:

http://www.anujgakhar.com/2011/11/22/phonegap-gotcha-error-whitelist-rejection/

> "In your PhoneGap.plist file, you need to add the allowed URLs to the ExternalHosts array. I added “*” as I did not want to add each individual URL separately to the list but that’s your choice."